# Hi there.. I'm trying to make a level up system and i don't get any errors in terminal but the json data doesn't updated

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Here is my code and as i said in terminal there are no errors but , json file doesn't updates yes my json file starts with {}
im not giving the full code but only necessary code to check..

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    json.load(f)
    users = await update_data(users, member)
  with open("users.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
   users = json.load(f)
  await update_data(users, message.author)
  await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
  await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
  with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
  if not user.id in users:
    users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
    users[user.id]]'level"] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  users [user.id]["experience"] += exp

async def level_up(users , user , channel):
  experience = users[user.id]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await ctx.send(channel , '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention , lvl_end))
    users[str(user.id)]["level"] = lvl_end
  
  with open("users.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users , f)
```

Comment: Why do you use `user.id` everywhere except the level_up routine, where you have `str(user.id)`?  Is it a string or an integer?

Comment: it is a integer

Comment: Then don't use `str(user.id)`.  It won't match the integer version.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    json.load(f)
```

That loads your JSON file and throws the results on the floor.  You wanted:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
```

You might consider writing "read_config" and "write_config" routines to encapsulate that, to avoid errors.